# Set user-defined cell value in Visio document shape sheet from a macro.

Tags: vba, visio

I added a row to the User-defined Cells section of the main Visio document shape sheet called User.Revision. I can use the value in the drawings by adding a field set to use a Custom Formula =TheDoc!User.Revision.

I would like to have a macro to set this Cell value but I can't find a way to reference the User-defined Cells in VBA. TheDoc!User.Revision doesn't work.

Comment: Try use syntax. CustomVariable.Formula = "TheDoc!User.Revision"

Comment: I'm not doing it right.

Sub SetRevision()
  Dim Message, Title, Default, MyValue
  Message = "Please enter the new revision marker."
  Title = "Revision"
  
  Default = CustomVariable.Formula = "TheDoc!User.Revision" ' This doesn't work ...
  
  MyValue = InputBox(Message, Title, Default)
  
  TheDoc!User.Revision = MyValue   'This doesn't work either but it doesnt _ get that far anyway ...
End Sub

Comment: I recorded a Macro to add a row in the User-defined cells section. I looked at how the row was inserted and how the formula (value) was referenced. It uses this syntax:

Application.ActiveWindow.Shape.CellsSRC(visSectionUser, 1, visUserValue).FormulaU


This works because the added row is the second row i.e. index of 1.


I Will have to iterate through to find the index of my row - where RowNameU = "Revision" if I want it to be reusable and robust.

Comment: I don't understand where you use this syntax. For shape's or document's level ?

Comment: Document level. I am using a User-defined Cell in the document shape sheet as the file revision. I place a field on each drawing so when it it printed or viewed I can tell which revision it is. I wanted an easy way to update the User-defined Cell so I don't have to open the document shape sheet every time because for some reason that is very slow.

Comment: you have multipage document with shapes with fields contain revision number on each page ?

Comment: I have a multi-page Visio document. I added one row in the User-defined Vells in the document shape sheet and called it "Revision". On each sheet in the document I have inserted a field that links to the User.Revision value (formula).

Comment: To set the value of this row from a macro I first need to find the row in a reliable way by iterating  through the User-defined Cells section of the document shape sheet until I find a row named "Revision". I'll get there somehow - but any advice would be appreciated. There seems to bed not much info around Visio macros.

Answer (score 1):

So this is a bit late, but I guess someone may still be able to use this.

The `ShapeSheet` of the document is called `DocumentSheet` and can be accessed like this:

```vb
Sub testReadWriteDocumentSheet()

    Dim someDoc As Visio.Document
    Set someDoc = ThisDocument 'or whatever other document you need

    Dim rowName As String 'the Name of the Row
    rowName = "ExampleRevision"

    Dim value As String 'the value you want to store, change to whatever format you need.
    value = "132ABC"

    'to set up the cell:
    PrepareCellOnDocumentSheet someDoc, rowName

    'to write
    someDoc.DocumentSheet.CellsU("User." & rowName).FormulaForceU = Chr$(34) & value & Chr$(34)
    'Chr$(34) is needed to add the quotes if you store a string,
    'if you store a Double or Long leave them out.

    'to read:
    Dim returnValue As String
    returnValue = someDoc.DocumentSheet.CellsU("User." & rowName).ResultStr(visNoCast)
    'returns the string but without the quotes
    Debug.Print returnValue

End Sub
```

Bonus:
This code automatically checks if the row (and User-Section) you ask for exists and if not adds them.

```vb
Private Function PrepareCellOnDocumentSheet(ByVal someDoc as Visio.Document, ByVal rowName As String)
    With someDoc.DocumentSheet
        If Not .SectionExists(visSectionUser, False) Then
            .AddSection visSectionUser
        End If
        If Not .CellExistsU("User." & rowName, True) Then
            .AddNamedRow visSectionUser, rowName, visTagDefault
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: I tried this code - fixing a typo or two - but invariably I get this error.

"Run-time error '-2032466967 (86db03e9)'.

Unexpected end of file."

Comment: This usually happens if you try to access a cell that does not exist.
That's what "PrepareCellOndocumentSheet" is for, it creates the row/cell if it not exists, just call it right before you try to read/write to the sheet

Comment: Typos fixed an code changed so it runs in a code module, just copy the whole thing to test it.